# AuthorizationFailed - Creating Role Assignments in Azure

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-managed-identity

I keep getting the **AuthorizationFailed** error when I try creating managed identity and assigning role assignments.
I have done this in the portal, but replicating in terraform has been a pain.

```
# User Assigned Managed Identity
resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "managed-id" {
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
  location            = var.location
  name                = var.name
  tags                = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "rg" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.id
  role_definition_name = "Contributor"
  principal_id         = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.managed-id.id
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "vnet" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.id
  role_definition_name = "Network Contributor"
  principal_id         = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.managed-id.id
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "dns" {
  count                = "${var.create_dns_ra ? 1 : 0}"
  scope                = data.azurerm_subscription.sub.id
  role_definition_name = "Private DNS Zone Contributor"
  principal_id         = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.managed-id.id
}
```

After the terraform apply, this is the error for the *rg* role assignment resource:

```
Error: authorization.RoleAssignmentsClient#Create: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The client '9219bxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx' with object id '9219xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' over scope '/subscriptions/4c4xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/test-RG/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/086bxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."
```

Similar error for the **vnet** role assignment resource:

```
Error: authorization.RoleAssignmentsClient#Create: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The client '9219bxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx' with object id '9219bxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' over scope '/subscriptions/4c4xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/test-RG/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/test-RG-vnet/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/55adxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."
```

I don't know what I need to get this going, but I'd appreciate any suggestions or solutions to this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To create role assignments, you need to assign either **User Access Administrator** or **Owner** role to your service principal that includes this permission: *"Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write"*

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got below results:***

I used below query to create role assignments for **resource group** and got **same error** as you like this:

```json
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subID>/resourceGroups/<rgname>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?api-version=2022-04-01
{
  "properties": {
    "roleDefinitionId": "/subscriptions/<subID>/resourceGroups/<rgname>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c",
    "principalId": "ca1xxx18-7561-4b98-987d-ee51xxxxd7"
  }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

I got **similar error** when I tried to create role assignments for **`VNet`** too like below:

```json
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subID>/resourceGroups/<rgname>/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/srivnet/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx?api-version=2022-04-01
{
  "properties": {
    "roleDefinitionId": "/subscriptions/<subID>/resourceGroups/<rgname>/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/srivnet/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c",
    "principalId": "ca1xxx18-7561-4b98-987d-ee51xxxxd7"
  }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, I assigned `Owner` role to the service principal under subscription like below:

[image]

After assigning that role, role assignments **created** successfully on resource group when I ran below query again:

[image]

In your case, try assigning your service principal **Owner** role under subscription to resolve the issue.

If you feel **Owner** role is more permissive, it's better to create custom RBAC role with *"Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write"* permission as suggested in below link.

**Reference:**
[Authorization failed when when writing a roleAssignment - Microsoft Q&A by **AmanpreetSingh-MSFT**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/287573/authorization-failed-when-when-writing-a-roleassig)

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to give this a shot.